# show data in list view in Sales Force?

Tags: android, android-listview, salesforce

I am new to Sales Force 
I want display list in Android program based on my Sales Force object data i was done the following steps:

based on call back and consumer key i successfully lo-gin to the API.and i navigate though all the controls in the trail version

how can i display the list of the items in Android Program is there any sample program to fetch and display data in the Android List view.please send any useful links to me to achieve this.

Thanks in Advance.....

Comment: From where you are fetching data?

Comment: Are you leveraging the SFDC Android Toolkit to login via OAuth2 (i.e. classes in the `com.sforce.android.soap.partner` namespace), or some other method?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to display the list of items using ListView .you can write a DataAdapter which extend BaseAdapter ,in the construtor method ,you set the data that you want to display as the parameter . then overwrite getView() method , you will make the item displayed .

key words: ListActivity , BaseAdapter.

Comment: how can i fetch data from salesforce?